# ¿Cómo valido si alguna línea de un txt está dentro de un string?

Tags: c++, archivo, txt

estoy intentando iterar sobre todas las líneas de un txt para validar si se encuentran dentro de un String que ingresa el usuario, para esto utilizo el getline que guarde el contenido de cada línea en una variable, y luego aplicar el .find con el string que se ingresa, pero al parecer, sólo reconoce la primera línea del archivo, y el .find sólo retorna válido si la palabra que busca está en la posición 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "funciones1.h"
using namespace std;

Frase::~Frase(){}
Frase::Frase(){}

string frase;

void buscar_elementos(){
string linea;
string var = frase;
  
ifstream archivo;
archivo.open("verbos.txt", ios::in);
  while(!archivo.eof()){
    getline(archivo, linea);
    if(var.find(linea) != string::npos){
        cout<<"Válido";
        break;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Inválido";
        break;
    }
  }
}


int main(){
  cin>>frase;
  buscar_elementos();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar información a las funciones es preferible usar los argumentos de la función. No conviene usar variables globales:

```
void buscar_elementos(string frase)
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    std::string frase;
    std ::cin >> frase;
    buscar_elementos(frase);
}
```

Por otro lado, date cuenta que `frase` no contiene una frase sino una única palabra. Para leer una frase necesitarías usar aquí también `getline`:

```
std::string frase;
std::getline(cin, frase);
buscar_elementos(frase);
```

Ahora vamos con el algoritmo de búsqueda

**no puedes etiquetar el resultado invalido hasta que no has terminado**

Fíjate que tu programa hace el chequeo del `else` desde la primera línea... está dentro del bucle:

```
while(!archivo.eof()){
  getline(archivo, linea);

  if(var.find(linea) != string::npos){
      cout<<"Válido";
      break;
  }
  else{  // <<--- ELSE
      cout << "Inválido";
      break;
  }
}
```

Sin embargo, no puedes saber si el resultado es inválido hasta que no has recorrido el fichero al completo. Usa una variable booleana para evaluar el resultado:

```
bool valido = false;

while (!valido || !archivo.eof())
{
    string linea;
    getline(archivo, linea);
    valido = (frase.find(linea) != string::npos);
}

if (valido)
{
    std::cout << "Valido\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Invalido\n";
}
```

Comment: Hola, antes que nada, gracias por tu ayuda, ahora tengo un problema, y es que el programa siempre imprime Válido, a pesar de que se ingresen palabras que no se encuentran en el txt, no sé a qué se deba, ya probé cambiando el operador del .find a == pero aún no funciona, así que creo que debe ser algo en el recorrido del archivo; algo extraño es que si creo la variable linea fuera del while, el programa no hace más nada luego de ingresar la frase. PD: tengo todo igual a la respuesta que propones.